# Скачивать картинки из файла и переименовывать сохраняя другое название

Tags: php

Есть длинный список
[image: длинный список товаров]

УРЛ картинки и артикул.

Подскажите, примерно как на PHP скормить данный список, чтобы скачивалось в определенную папку с названием в виде его артикула.

Я думаю файл назвать и запустить из корня сайта city.ru/upload.php

1. В нем указываю ссылку на список это может быть текстовый файл.
2. Перебирает массивом
3. Переименовывает
4. И скачивает в папку city/new_upload/

Примерно какие функции на PHP за что отвечают и как заставить перейти на картинку скачивая переименовывать?

Answer (score 1):

Если в общих чертах: экспортируете свой список в CSV, парсите его в скрипте для получения URL картинки и имени для будущего файла, делаете HTTP запрос при помощи curl, сохраняете результат в переменную, а затем пишете в файл в нужной директории с требуемым именем.

Может быть примерно как-то так:

```
$file = fopen('table.csv', 'r');

while ($line = fgetcsv($file, null, ',')) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $line[1]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $image= fopen('city/new_upload/' . $line[2] . '.jpg', 'w+');
    fwrite($image, $result);
    fclose($image);
}
```